# jQuery extract filename by using the variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on my jQuery as I want to extract the filename so I can output them in the element when I am fetching the data from an Ajax call.

If I have the string `0.2` using the variable `attid`, I want to fetch the filename `what-is-bootstrap.png`. If I have the string `0.1` using the variable `attid`, I want to fetch the filename `noname.gif` and so on.

But when I try this:

```
var photoFilename = filename.split('filename: ');
$('#photo_filename').text(photoFilename1);
$('#photo_dialog').show();
```

I will get something like this:

```
noname.gif attid: 0.2
```

I have also tried this:

```
var photoFilename = filename.split('attid: ');
```

And I have also tried this:

```
var photoFilename = filename.split(attid);
```

I will get this:

```
 filename: noname.gif attid: 0.2 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png
```

I have tried to use `.replace` function to remove the `attid: 0.2` but my variable `attid` are showing a different string so it is hard for me to remove the string for `0.2` when I have `0.1` string.

Can you please show me an example of how I can fetch the filename when my variable `attid` with the string like `0.1`, `0.2`, etc.

Here is the full code:

```
attid = '0.1'
get_string = 'attid: ' +attid+ ' filename: ';

$.ajax({
    url: 'readMail.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {
        mailfolder: mailfolder, 
        email_number: email_number,
        folder: folder,
        readmail: readmail,
        total: total_index
    },
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(res) {
        filename = res.emailBodyMessage.attached_files;
        var photoFilename = filename.split(get_string);
        $('#photo_filename').text(photoFilename1);
        $('#photo_dialog').show();
   }
});
```

Full output:

```
attid: 0.1 filename: noname.gif
attid: 0.2 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png
```

Comment: based on your code photoFilename1 would be undefined right? or did you mean photoFilename[1]? if so, then all you have to do is split it again like this photoFilename[1].split(" ")[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully my snippet can help you in some way..

```js
// function to grab filename
function getFileName(text, key) {
  delimiter = "attid: "+key+" filename: "
  return (text.split(delimiter))[1].split(" ")[0]
}

// example text
text = "attid: 0.1 filename: noname.gif attid: 0.2 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png attid: 0.3 filename: something.bmp"

// get 0.1
file1 = getFileName(text, "0.1");

// get 0.2
file2 = getFileName(text, "0.2");

// get 0.3
file3 = getFileName(text, "0.3");

//print to console
console.log(file1, file2, file3)
```

UPDATE!!

```
attid = '0.1'
get_string = 'attid: ' +attid+ ' filename: ';

$.ajax({
    url: 'readMail.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {
        mailfolder: mailfolder, 
        email_number: email_number,
        folder: folder,
        readmail: readmail,
        total: total_index
    },
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(res) {
        filename = res.emailBodyMessage.attached_files;
        var photoFilename = filename.split(get_string);

        // please try to update this line :)
        $('#photo_filename').text(photoFilename[1].split(" ")[0]);

        $('#photo_dialog').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, is it possible if you could make some change without a function?

Comment: yeah sure, but before i do that, can you please try my update?

Comment: hifebriansyah I have try it as it works great thanks, but there is a problem. When I click on the first image, it works fine but when I click on the second image, I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`. The string and code I am using is the same as yours.

Comment: There is no error from readMail.php, the error is coming from this line `$('#photo_filename').text(photoFilename[1].split(" ")[0]);`

Comment: hifebriansyah Oppps, sorry I make a mistake. I have accident put the `filename = '';` in the click button event, this is why I got an error so when I got rid it and it works fine. Problem are now resolved!

Comment: @RobertJones nice to hear!

Answer (score 0):

By using `split` and `for` loop with `indexOf` .. See the next code

```js
var string = "attid: 0.1 filename: noname.gif attid: 0.2 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png"; // The String Here

console.log(Get_FileName_By_attid(string , '0.1'));


function Get_FileName_By_attid(string , attid){
  var string_split = string.split(/attid/g);
  for(var i = 1 ; i < string_split.length ; i++){
    var NewString = "attid" + string_split[i];
    if(NewString.indexOf(attid) > -1){
      return ((NewString.split('filename:'))[1].trim());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mohamed-Yousef it look good but unforunately I want to use without json. Can you change it to make it more similar like using my code? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

var photoFilename = filename.split(' ')[3];
split() returns an array, and js srrays are zero-based so [3] is actually the fourth element